# The Podfile contains framework or static library targets (UnityFramework), for which the Podfile does not contain host targets

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, frameworks, cocoapods

after exporting my Unity project and try to update pod,

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and

```
pod update
```

I got this message

> [!] The Podfile contains framework or static library targets
> (UnityFramework), for which the Podfile does not contain host targets
> (targets which embed the framework). If this project is for doing
> framework development, you can ignore this message. Otherwise, add a
> target to the Podfile that embeds these frameworks to make this
> message go away (e.g. a test target).

this is the SDK list the pod updated and installed

```
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (5.6.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (5.6.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (5.6.0)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.66.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (6.9.0)
Installing GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (1.2.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (6.7.2)
Installing PromisesObjC (1.2.11)
Installing nanopb (1.30906.0)
```

the podfile is very simple, just `target 'UnityFramework' do` the above SDKs

this is the first time I got this message, after updating my os to Catalina and Xcode to 12

but, when I test the app or build, everything works fine,

so, if everything works fine, should I ignore this message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me pod install shows this message because i has a proxy so pod can't download files
Once i delete all proxy everything works